# Apache wicket upgrade

Tags: migration, wicket-7

I've Recently started working on a project that was developed almost a decade ago, The current Wicket version used in the project is Wicket 1.3, which has reached End of life. They have recently upgraded java to jdk7 on their production servers. This is the very first time i get a chance to work on wicket. I've been asked to do a feasibility study and provide an effort/cost estimate. I am thinking like "Can't we directly Upgrade to wicket 7.0.0 from wicket 1.3.5?" In such a case do i have to consider the changes (Modified/deprecated) in the intermediary releases of Apache Wicket viz , Wicket 1.4, 1.5, 1.6. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a lot of changes between 1.3 and 7.0, how much of this impacts your application will of course depend on how much of wicket you are using.

Take a look through the migration guide here:
http://wicket.apache.org/start/wicket-7.x.html#migrate

You won't be able to just drop in the new wicket 7 JARs into you project and nothing more I'm afraid, it probably wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

There have been many methods and classes which have been deprecated. Furthermore there have been many changes to the existing classes such as IVisitor, IBehavior etc.

The 1.3 to 7 undertaking will be a lot of work. 
 
I'd recommend starting with an upgrade to 1.5.
 The upgrades from 1.5 to 6 and then 7 shouldn't be as terrible as going 1.3 to 7 directly.